# Can a certain part of human dna can be replaced with other animals dna?

Tags: dna

Human DNA consists of adenine, thymine, guanine and cytosine. Can thymine of other animal can be placed with humans thymine?

Comment: First: the whole base is called thymidine (consists of thymin and the ribose). There is no difference between thymidine of human or animal origin.

Comment: @Chris so that we can replace?

Comment: Where and what do you want to replace?

Comment: Thymine in all living things is identical.  It has been possible to use the chemicals from plants animals or bacteria (or organic chemistry) in human cells....

Answer (score 3):

Yes. They're identical. When we eat animals or plants we digest their DNA to use to make our own DNA.

Comment: Sweet, sweet DNA...